# How to use Progress indicator in cocoa within action method

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have a register button. When the button is pressed my action method `register()` will be called. To perform some registration I am calling an executable within register function as NSAppleScript with administrator privileges. Execution of this will take 10-20 seconds.

I defined an outlet within my controller class for the progress indicator---> say process.

If I call `[process startAnimation:sender]` within `register:sender` function, I will see the indicator on the window after register function execution. [once the register function ends, the indicator starts running]

```
-(void)register:(id)sender{
    [process startAnimation:sender] ;
    ////
    NSAppleScript *applescript   //define
                                 //run it here
    ///
```

I can't change anything in my executable. I want the indicator to spin within the register method itself.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then I think the best way would be to create a new thread (blocks if you are on iOS5). Run the executable in the new thread and spinner in the main thread.